# Encryption of binary

Tags: math, encryption, binary, permutation

Suppose I have 8 bits. Then total possible combinations would be 2^8 . Is there some encryption technique I could use so that I can identify all those 256 numbers with less bits ( say 5 or 6 bits). I know this is kind of hard ( and impossible ) . But if someone could help.

Comment: Encryption does not compress data, perhaps you mean encoding.

Comment: I really meant encryption. I thought there could be a way to form a new encrypted data that could resolve it with less bits. For example if we see 2^8 bits in 16x16 matrix and number rows and columns from 0 to 31 and some how could encrypt the data in 2^5 form.

Comment: No what you wan to is not encryption. Encryption does not decrease the size of data. it just changes it into another form of the same or slightly larger size based on a key. Later the encrypted data can be restored wth the use of the same key. (Asymmetric key encryption is slightly different but again does not decrease the size of the data). What you want is a 5 kg bag that will hold 8 kg.

Comment: Imagine you knew a method which could squeeze 8 bits into 6. Then you could repeat that process over and over again, converting Terabyte of data to literally nothing. Sounds somehow wrong, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

At least 2 of the original 256 states would be mapped to the same encoded state. Therefore you cannot reconstruct the original stated from the encoded state.

see [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Please read my comment on question. I am not trying to violate pigeonhole. I am trying to keep two numbers( <16) in 5 bits some how. By some bit encryption. I am not dealing with the bits as numbers. But as if the first bit helps in finding whether number is divisible by two then next by three so that i could find two numbers hidden.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) there's no there's no way to stuff 8 bits of information in 5 or 6 without loss of data.

With *larger* sets of data you can use [lossless compression techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) to reduce the amount of data needed, but those techniques have overhead that would take more information than could be saved from just 8 bits.

The only way you can compress 8 bits is to restrict the data set so that patterns can be encoded.  e.g. if exactly one of the first two bits can be `1` then you can "encode" that to save one bit, but that limits the number possible values to 
2^7.

Comment: Please read my comment on question. I am not trying to violate pigeonhole. I am trying to keep two numbers( <16) in 5 bits some how. By some bit encryption. I am not dealing with the bits as numbers. But as if the first bit helps in finding whether number is divisible by two then next by three so that i could find two numbers hidden.